# Количество дней каждого месяца текущего года

Tags: bash, дата

Хочу получить строку из количества дней каждого месяца года. Задача стоит получать ее именно динамически, а не путем записи в переменную чего-то вроде `31 28 31...` с последующей проверкой является ли год високосным или нет и правкой ее через `sed`. Как это сделать через однострочник?

Answer (score 2):

Можно предварительно и не объявлять переменную.

```
sed 's/28/'"$(date -d "2 + 1 month - 1 day" +%d)/g" <<< '31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31'
```

Или можно поступить так:

```
seq 12 | xargs -i bash -c 'cal `date +"{} %Y"` | awk "NF{x=\$NF};END{printf \"%d \", x}"'
```

Без использования `cal`:

```
echo $(seq 12 | xargs -i date -d "`date +"%Y-{}-1"`+1month-1day" +%d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for m in $(seq 1 12); do 
  date -d "$(date "+%Y")-01-01 + $m month - 1 day" +%d;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..12}; do date -d "`date +%Y-$i-01` -1 day + 1 month" +'%B - %d day';done
```

Где `for i in {1..12}; do` цикл делающий счет от 1 до 12
команда `` date -d "`date +%Y-%m-01` +1 month -1day" +'%B - %d day' `` выведет количество дней в текущем месяце

В случае чего можно сделать функцию:

```
countdate () {
Year=${1:-`date +%Y`}
echo "Год: $Year"
for i in {1..12}; do
    date -d "`date +$Year-$i-01` -1 day + 1 month" +'%B - %d day'
done
}
```

После чего вызывать ее одной строкой:
`countdate 2018` - покажет информацию по дням за 2018 год
`countdate` - покажет информацию за 2020

Answer (score 0):

seq, xargs, grep, cal, date, cut и tr, для красоты.

```
seq 12|xargs -i sh -c 'LC_ALL=C cal 31 {} $(date +%Y) 2>&1|grep -Eo "\-(2[8|9])|\-30|31"|cut -d "-" -f 2|tr "\n" " "'
```

Пользуемся STDERR разговорчивостью cal ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 
#(рабочее)
#...
months=();
for ((im=02; im !=13; im++))
            do
                months[${#months[@]}]=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-$im-01) -1 
day"|awk '{print$2}');#"
        done
                months[${#months[@]}]=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-01-01) +1 
year -1 day"|awk '{print$2}');#"
echo -e ${months[@]};
#...
```

почему сейчас написал, да потому, что примеры хоть и похожи на правду, но не работают в bash(Linux) и когда мне самому это понадобилось, кучу времени убил просто на поиски..
отдельное спасибо - [sys-adm.in](https://sys-adm.in/os/nix/646-rabota-s-formatami-dat-v-bash.html?ysclid=l1vi4o5vxe)